# How to access windows relative paths (e.g. %userprofile%) in matlab?

Tags: windows, matlab, path, relative-path

I'd like to get a relative path in matlab (e.g. 'C:/Users/thisuser/THATFOLDER'). I read on unix machines you may use ~, however I'm working on a windows system.

Is there a workaround? Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get general windows env settings using:

```
userFolder = getenv ( 'userprofile' )
```

so to get `THATFOLDER` use:

```
fullfile ( userFolder, 'THATFOLDER' )
```

In one line:

```
fullfile ( getenv ( 'userprofile' ), 'THATFOLDER' );
```

Comment: Trying to put this in a one-liner: Using [getenv ('userprofile') '\THATFOLDER'] I get:
_Error using getenv_
_Not enough input arguments._
anyway around this?

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that THATFOLDER might not necessarily be where you are expecting it to be.  For example, the user's Documents folder might not be inside the user's profile at all.  (This typically isn't a problem if you are writing code for in-house use.)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the full path by using the function `system`:

For example

```
[~,cmdout] = system('echo %APPDATA%')
```

Should give you the full appdata path.

Comment: thanks, both answers are equally correct in my eyes, however getenv seems more specific (but the system command more useful for general adaptation)